# Databricks code does not work anymore with 'directory not found' error

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, databricks-community-edition

This is from an SO-question some 4 years ago. It worked in Databricks Notebook.

```
%python
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = """
CODE,L,PS
5d8A,N,P60490
5d8b,H,P80377
5d8C,O,P60491
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep=',')
#print(df)
df.to_csv('/dbfs/FileStore/NJ/file1.txt')

pandas_df = pd.read_csv("/dbfs/FileStore/NJ/file1.txt", header='infer') 
print(pandas_df)
```

Now it does not. Error message is:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dbfs/FileStore/NJ/file1.txt'
```

Curious what the issue is. As the directory is there.

Comment: Are you using a shared cluster? Does the `/FileStore/NJ/` exists on DBFS? What is environment - community edition, aws/azure? What DBR version?

Comment: Community Edition where I try various things. Too expensive - if not using at work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from DBR 7.x, the `/dbfs/` (so-called fuse mount) is disabled on the Databricks community edition due to some reasons (maybe for security, but I don't remember).

The current workaround is to use `dbutils.fs.cp` (or `dbutils.fs.mv`) to copy files between DBFS & local file system, and working with files locally.  (if URI scheme isn't specified, then it's DBFS by default).

To copy from DBFS to local file system:

```py
dbutils.fs.cp("/path-on-dbfs", "file:/local-path")
```

To copy from local file system to DBFS:

```py
dbutils.fs.cp("file:/local-path", "/path-on-dbfs")
```